# Stirling number of the first kind summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

I'm calculating some probability and confronted such an exotic summation:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k+c\brack k}
$$
where ${k+c\brack k}$ is unsigned Stirling number of the first kind and $c$ is a constant value. Is there a shorter form for such a summation? I mean as an explicit function of $n$.

Comment: When $c=1$ the answer is the [tetrahedral numbers](http://oeis.org/A000292). Already when $c=2$ the resulting sequence doesn't seem to be in the OEIS, so it might not have a nice closed form.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks a lot. But it can be calculated for any specific $c$ as a polynomial of $n$. Since the Stirling number of the first kind ( s(n,k) ) can be represeted as a polynomial of $n$ if $k$ is specified.

Comment: @GregMartin Now, see this link. Does anything change? (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3633357/649062)